# Background of TextView with multiple lines not wrapping correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

**Background:**

I've got a layout that consists of 6 items layed out as a grid (2x3). All items are as wide as half the screen (minus a little margin on each side). Each item is a `RelativeLayout` that contains an  `ImageView` (the background) and a `TextView` (the label). The label is set to wrap the text, and it's allowed to grow almost as wide as the image it sits on top of. After that it will break into two lines.

**Problem:**

Everything looks good as long as the text fits on a single line (see top element in picture). The background wraps the text nicely. However, when the text is displayed on two lines the background gets too wide (see bottom item in picture). It fills up the maximum allowed width even though the text on the first line doesn't take up that much space. Is there a way to make the background wrap the text in the same way as it does when only one line is used?

**Picture:**

[image: screen_capture]

**Layout XML:**

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <!-- some stuff I had to remove... -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="11.33333dp">

        <!-- some other stuff I had to remove... -->

        <!-- the gray background color is set to the TextView below programmatically together with the text itself. -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_text_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5.33333dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7.33333dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5.33333dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibility of such problem is `textSize`.

It depends on how you are setting and which measuring unit you are using to set `textSize` of your `TextView`.

`dp,sp,pt and in` may cause to create such problems.

So try to go with `mm` or `px` specifically.

And as per my testing `px` will give you the best result.

**EDITED :**

Add following attribute to your `TextView` in layout file.

```
android:gravity="right|start"
```

Instead of :

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using dp at the moment. Tried with px instead but it didn't make any difference at all. :/

Comment: I can see difference on my screen and when I use `dp` or `pt` it showing problem like you have posted but when I use `px` it works perfectly.

Comment: If it was only a measuring problem of the text width, wouldn't I see the same problem for the label with one line? It's only when it wraps to a second line that the width stays to the maximum width instead of the actual width of the text on the first line.

Comment: @TofferJ look at the edited solution I have posted that might solve your problem.

Comment: If I add the "|start" part the text just ends up left aligned instead. The margin to the left is correct, but the TextView is still wider than it needs to be. Anyway, left aligned is not an option. Thanks anyway for the effort!